# Blank space under menu after scrolling on mobile devices

Tags: css, mobile, scroll, frontend

I have position fixed menu element which is hiding whenever you click/touch on darken area. And the problem is that whenever you are scrolling website this blank space appears under menu before it hides

screenshot with issue:
[image: screenshot with issue].

I tried to add more height to menu element and setting overflow: hidden to disable scrolling when menu is active but it didn't help. Also i tried to search about this but it's really hard for me to formulate accurate question with words to find some related answers or tips.

Comment: Can your try `height: 100vh;` instead of `height: 100%;`  ?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I tried it but it don't quite do anything, because position fixed is relative to the screen so 100% equals 100vh :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how actually **position: fixed** is working, and came up with idea how can i solve my issue. So basically, on touch devices position fixed is working only in one way(for example: if you set **top: 0** and **bottom: auto**(or **top: 0** and **bottom: 0**), there will be an empty space at bottom before menu hides, and if you set **bottom: 0** and **top: auto** there will be opposite effect). So i came up with idea to create another layer with same bg-color and same animation effects but with **bottom: 0** and **top: auto** for preventing this blank space on top/bottom side of the menu. So basically, yea, it did solve my issue. Maybe someone is facing same, so i decided to write down this answer.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @eisbehr for teaching me how to use this and a well learned lesson, I removed my previous answer.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.forceHeight {
  position: relative;
  height: 200vh;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="forceHeight">
  <div class="menu">
    this is your fixed menu
  </div>
  asdf this has a lot of content
</div>
```

Comment: It didn't helped me. Actually this blank space only appears on touch devices. And on built in chrome device emulator everything working as excepted. I think it's related to same behaviour on top and bottom edges of page too. You know, like when the page is on the edge and you scroll the whole page is moving and there is like same blank space. I hope you get what am i talking about. Sorry for my english :)

Comment: @menberusch can you please provide a reproduceable example of your bug?

Comment: 1) https://i.imgur.com/AXCZU1U.jpg 2) https://i.imgur.com/odMmeLV.jpg    
Second image is after scrolling on the top of page. About this i was talking in my previous comment